# jQuery Autocomplete and Angular http returns errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, autocomplete

So I am using an ajax autocomplete for my database using [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) and this is my current code:

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-keyup="searchCustomer()" id="customerAutocomplete" type="text">
```

**Angular**

```
    $scope.searchCustomer = function () {
        $http.get('/api/customers') //this is a json return
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data); //FIRST OUTPUT
                $('#customerAutocomplete').autocomplete({
                    lookup: response.data,
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

The output in my console whenever I type something is this:

[image]

As you can see, it returns the console.log but there's an error and there's no autocomplete showing.

In the usage part of [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete), there is the part that I had tried and it worked.

```
var countries = [
    { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
    { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

But whenever I change the countries variable for my own data from http call, I'm still getting the error.

I checked the line 85th of the library

[image]

and it's `return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) !== -1;`.

So my first guess is to `JSON.stringify` the `response.data` and then I get this:

[image]

So it didn't work too. Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

As per `jQuery-Autocomplete` [documentation](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#response-format) Response from the server must be JSON formatted following JavaScript object  as below :

```
{
  // Query is not required as of version 1.2.5
  "query": "Unit",
  "suggestions": [
    { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
    { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
    { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
  ]
}
```

Or you need to use [transformResult](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#non-standard-queryresults) function to parse your API response to standard response.

I think, in your case it should be like below :

// HTML

```
<input id="customerAutocomplete" type="text">
```

// Script

```
$('#customerAutocomplete').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl : '/api/customers', // your full api URL
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  transformResult: function(response) {
    if(response.data.length > 0 ) {
      return {
        suggestions: $.map(response.data, function(dataItem) {
            return { value: dataItem.customer_name, data: dataItem.customer_id };
        })
      };
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: in this part suggestions: $.map(response.data, function (dataItem)

Comment: i have updated my answer as i think `searchCustomer` function is not needed. so make other change accordingly.